# I am trying to write login logic but its throwing me SQLiteDatabaseException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception

Ok so what i want to do is to login in the app. But Its throwing me the SQLiteDatabaseException.
Below is the function:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private EditText LOGIN_ID;
    private EditText LOGIN_PASS;
    private Button LOGIN;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        initializeUI();
    }
    public void initializeUI(){
        LOGIN_ID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginID);
        LOGIN_PASS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        LOGIN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    }
    public void loginProcess(View view){
            LOGIN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        database db = new database(LoginActivity.this);
                        int id = db.login(LOGIN_ID.getText().toString(), LOGIN_PASS.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LandingActivity.class));
                        new LandingActivity(id);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Login Error");
                        builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                        builder.show();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

So Above is the LoginActivity.java file. And The Below function fetches the info from database.

```
    public int login(String loginId,String loginPass)throws Exception{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int ID1 = Integer.parseInt(loginId);
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+tableName+" WHERE "+ID_COL+" = "+ID1+" AND "+PASS_COL+" = "+loginPass+";";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    int login_id = cursor.getInt(Id);
    return login_id;
}
```

And The Error:
This is the Error its Throwing.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 2320
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@123": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM customer WHERE ID = 101 AND PASS = Test@123;
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
at com.example.myapplication.database.login(database.java:80)
at com.example.myapplication.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:34)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: Please don't post (or *try to* post!!) code or error messages as images.  Copy the text into your question.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: Well, the error message says you have a syntax error in your SQL.  There should be quotes around the value you want `PASS` be equal to.

Comment: Ok i will check

Comment: And [never use string contatenation to generate SQL statements](https://xkcd.com/327/). Use prepared statements.

Comment: And of course: never ever store raw passwords in your database. Repeat: you never store the original unencrypted password in the database! (read about hashing and such)